# STRAPI : Error while running command develop: undefined

Tags: strapi

I am not able to `npm start` STRAPI, it shows follwiting error. I'm using `STRAPI 3.1.3`

```
> my-project@0.1.0 strapi /Users/mac/Documents/Development_env/jobBackend/my-project
> strapi "develop"

Error while running command develop: undefined
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-prject@0.1.0 strapi: `strapi "develop"`    npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
macs-Air:my-project mac$ npm start

> my-project@0.1.0 start /Users/mac/Documents/Development_env/jobBackend/my-project
> strapi start

Error while running command start: undefined
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-project@0.1.0 start: `strapi start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-project@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mac/.npm/_logs/2020-08-13T17_02_08_854Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this error too. I upgraded to `strapi 3.1.4` and got a more useful error indicating a syntax error in one of my functions files. After fixing that, `strapi` commands worked as ever.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm run build
npm start
```

Or install `strapi-cli` globally using below command.

```
npm install -g strapi@beta
```

After successful installation use

```
strapi develop
```

to start the project